# Detect Column containing special characters other than ',' and '\n' - Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to find the values from a text column which have characters other than ',' and '\n'.

I am trying with using not like as below but it fetch all the records. so can anyone help us to get the expected results

```
select * from table where name not like '%\n%';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an `E` right before your string to [escape](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-syntax-lexical.html) the `\n`:

```
select * from table where name not like E'%\n%';
```

Demo:

```
WITH j (val) AS (
  VALUES(E'foo\n'),('bar')
)
SELECT * FROM j
WHERE val NOT LIKE E'%\n%';
 val 
-----
 bar
(1 row)
```